# Grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, url

I receive 50 entries from an URL in Cocoa Touch. These entries comes with a category and I would like to group these.

```
        for(NSString *category in listOfTime){
            // Now we have the category of the entry.
        }
```

How do I manage to group these entries and give them to a UITableView?

Comment: Have you read the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)? This question is too general for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I already got a full functional UITableView but only with unsorted entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial for starting out with UITableViews:

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/